# How to use pre-defined SSM Windows patch baselines in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-systems-manager

I'm creating a Systems Manager patch baseline in CloudFormation to automatically apply OS updates for my Windows EC2 instances:

```
  Windows2016PatchBaseline:
    Type: AWS::SSM::PatchBaseline
    Properties:
      Name: Windows2016PatchBaseline
      Description: Baseline containing all updates approved for Windows 2016 instances
      OperatingSystem: WINDOWS
      PatchGroups:
      - Windows Server 2016 Base   
      ApprovalRules:
        PatchRules:
        - PatchFilterGroup:
            PatchFilters:
            - Values:
              - Critical
              - Important
              - Moderate
              Key: MSRC_SEVERITY
            - Values:
              - SecurityUpdates
              - CriticalUpdates
              Key: CLASSIFICATION
            - Values:
              - WindowsServer2016
              Key: PRODUCT
          ApproveAfterDays: 7
          ComplianceLevel: CRITICAL
```

But, I can see there's a [predefined baseline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-patch-baselines.html) that does most of this configuration. I'd like to use this predefined baseline rather than creating my own, but I can't see any way of using it in CloudFormation's `AWS::SSM::PatchBaseline`.

Has any one done this before or is it possibly only available through the console?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
  MaintenanceWindowRunCommandTask:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTask'
    Properties:
      WindowId: !Ref MaintenanceWindow
      Targets:
        - Key: WindowTargetIds
          Values:
            - !Ref MaintenanceWindowTarget
      TaskArn: AWS-RunPatchBaseline
      TaskType: RUN_COMMAND
      TaskInvocationParameters:
        MaintenanceWindowRunCommandParameters:
          DocumentHash: 945ae15356b0f6ba7bce2a738101b8822cedef3bf5c027abc3bb9023aaec8b1b
          DocumentHashType: Sha256
          NotificationConfig:
            NotificationArn: !Ref MaintenanceTargetSNSARN
            NotificationEvents: 
              - All
            NotificationType: Command
          OutputS3BucketName: !Ref MaintenanceRunCommandS3Bucket
          OutputS3KeyPrefix: !Ref MaintenanceRunCommandS3BucketPrefix
```

Take a look at my SystemsManager templates I have here: https://github.com/Talderon/AWS_CloudFormation/tree/master/SystemsManager

Look at the WIKI pages in my repo as I have documented everything there as well.

Comment: The only problem I have with this is the hard coded hash of the document. As I am looking now the SHA has changed to 37a0106f43a26d81d70c4180b59cc24f29c8b36c3585c5785c62638bdea780ef

There has to be a way to get this dynamically

Comment: I am sure there may be a way to get this programmatically, but I have not really put too much effort that way since these do not change much and the tech-debt is acceptable for now. This is on a to-do list, but that's also on the low-hanging-fruit part of the tree. :)

Comment: Omitting DocumentHash & DocumentHashType will just run the document with $DEFAULT version